# How to save pickle files through cycles in Heroku python

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord.py, pickle

I have a discord.py bot that I am making that relies on storing data for long periods. To do this through cycles I thought I could use pickle, but the pickle file is reset to deployment every cycle also. Is there a way around this?

Comment: damn sorry for this repeat, I thought I would be able to do this project for free :(

Comment: You could use something like the [MongoDB Atlas free tier](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/free-your-genius-on-mongodb-atlas-free-tier)